# python 3d list manipulation

Tags: python, list, 3d, 2d

I have a 3d list
aa = [[[2, 3, 4, 5],
[ 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[11, 12, 14, 15]]], which consists of two 2d lists
how do I get this result
`[[2, 6], [11]]` 
the first element of each sub list.

```
b = []
for i, row in enumerate(aa):
  for j, rr in enumerate(row):
    b.append(rr[0])
```

gives
`[2,6,11]`

Comment: flaten the list and get the first element or through recursion get the first element

Comment: @sahasrara62 how would flattening the list help?

Comment: @Nin17 flaten the nested list of list to 1 level and then the first value from each sublist

Comment: @sahasrara62 the desired result is ```[[2, 6], [11]]``` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
[[i[0] for i in j] for j in aa]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 6], [11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store each first element in a sublist and merge those sublists to get your result

arr here is your input array

```
ret = []
for twoD in arr:
    temp=[]
    for oneD in twoD:
        temp.append(oneD[0])
    ret.append(temp)
print(ret)
```

Output

```
[[2, 6], [11]]
```